# Передача переменной в SQL запрос в PyQt5 с использованием QSqlQueryModel

Tags: python, python-3.x, sql, pyqt5

Всех приветствую, есть вот такой код:

```
model = QSqlQueryModel()
model.setQuery("SELECT id, \
                type_of_insurance AS Тип_страхования, \
                insurer AS Страховщик,\
                policyholder AS Страхователь,\
                insured AS Застрахованное_лицо,\
                validity AS Срок_действия,\
                from_date AS С,\
                until_date AS По,\
                countries AS Территория_действия,\
                insurance_amount AS Страховая_сумма,\
                contribution AS Страховой_взнос,\
                when_payment AS Тарифный_план,\
                how_payment AS Способ_оплаты \
                FROM contracts \
                WHERE id = **???**")
contracts_view_window.tableView.setModel(model)
contracts_view_window.tableView.show()
```

Собственно вопрос: как мне подставить вместо вопросов мою переменную:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Попробуйте так:

```
model.setQuery(
    """SELECT 
           id, 
           type_of_insurance AS Тип_страхования, 
           insurer AS Страховщик,
           policyholder AS Страхователь,
           insured AS Застрахованное_лицо,
           validity AS Срок_действия,
           from_date AS С,
           until_date AS По,
           countries AS Территория_действия,
           insurance_amount AS Страховая_сумма,
           contribution AS Страховой_взнос,
           when_payment AS Тарифный_план,
           how_payment AS Способ_оплаты 
       FROM contracts 
       WHERE id = '{}'
""".format(id_db))
```

Comment: У меня получилось вот так вот:
`... 
 FROM contracts \
 WHERE insured LIKE %s" %(insured_text))`

Comment: @Игорь можно и так, но не понял, у вас так как предложил я - не получилось ?

Comment: я не пробовал ;)

Comment: @Игорь мне жаль потраченного времени на подготовку и 
опубликование ответа для вас.

Comment: Извините, мне жаль. Я проверил, ваш запрос работает.
В любом случае спасибо за потраченное время, поверьте, мне очень приятно!